# How can i convert [AnyHashable: Any] to [String: Any] in swift ios

Tags: swift

This kind of data i am getting in this format [AnyHashable: Any]:

[AnyHashable("mobile"): 1234567890, AnyHashable("device-id"): BE7HA05F-7C5B-40BA-A10C-0C5AJ7GEFC3F,  AnyHashable("os"): ios]

I want to get it as [String: Any] (without AnyHashable keyword) or in JSON format, How can i achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cast the type `as? [String:Any]` or if it's guaranteed that all keys are `String` do `as! [String:Any]`

Answer (score 0):

If all keys in your dictionary are in fact `String`s, you can simply cast using `as? [String: Any]`.

If there are any non-String keys, you can try this:

```
let input: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
    "mobile": 1234567890,
    "device-id": "BE7HA05F-7C5B-40BA-A10C-0C5AJ7GEFC3F",
    "os": "ios",
    1: 2
]

let output = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.compactMap { k, v -> (String, Any)? in
    if let ks = k as? String {
        return (ks, v)
    }
    return nil
})

print(output)
```